# copyToRealm() don't paste data in variable

Tags: android, database, realm

I have save POJO in Realm DB in this code:

```
public void saveUser(SoftDesignUser user) {
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    SoftDesignUser realmUser = mRealm.copyToRealm(user);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

But all variables set null, although the data is stored in the description.
[Debug Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOMBI.png)

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look of this https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#testing-and-debugging